# How powerful are air cannons?

Tags: physics, sound, machines

I wondered how powerful [air blasters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_blaster) are.

Is it possible for one to be so powerful that the shock wave passes through walls, floors and ceilings? Could it make bumps on metallic surfaces or at least an audible noise, like a pebble falling on it?

The reason I ask, is that I'm trying to debunk a claim that someone is being assaulted by a neighbor through some kind of sound waves or pressure waves. I'm highly skeptical, but I'm trying to figure out a possible mechanism in the eventuality the person is right, and the only reasonable thing I could come up with is a pressure cannon.

Comment: If it’s used for de-clogging it obviously has more force than a falling pebble. So, yes, it could make a noise on a metal surface, it can potentially dent it (if concentrated enough) and so on.

Comment: @Konrad: air by itself? no way. If you'd use air blaster to launch something solid, then maybe.

Comment: Remember that air is essentially a liquid. A solid wall would act as a barrier to the waves.

Comment: @Math: a gas, liquids do not compress.

Comment: @MathMike perhaps you meant fluid, and not liquid?

Comment: yes. fluid. I'm going to the penalty box now to feel shame for the next 2 minutes.

Comment: @MathMike Well you can cause dents and noises with water, too. The *force* is decisive here.

Comment: I dunno about the specific type of air blaster that you listed, but a vortex cannon is definitely capable of doing damage using only an air vortex. Here's a video (with an annoying presenter): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IyAyd4WnvhU&feature=player_detailpage

Comment: Air is matter. It has mass, momentum, kinetic, potential, and heat energy. When I fly, its momentum holds my plane up. Ever see those videos of nuclear bomb blasts? The damage is done by *air* transmitting the energy (and by the light).

Comment: Well, I don't think anyone is gonna use such a potent cannon in his house to trouble a neighbor. I don't see how he would be able to avoid destroying his own home in the process. But it confirms what I thought, that it's completely fantastic to think something like that is going on.

Comment: correct. A shockwave powerful enough to destroy things on the other side of a solid wall is powerful enough to bring down that wall :)

Comment: Define "being assaulted". A comment to an answer below seems to presume assulted = knocked over, as in literally being made to fall to the floor from a standing position. If assulted here means something more subtle then it's possible that it's infrasound.

Comment: could a magnetic device do this?

Answer (score 3):

Given the reason for your question, I'd suggest an [air vortex cannon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_vortex_cannon) as another device that could be used to that effect.

On that basis, I will answer **yes** — air vortex cannons can knock over brick walls: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IyAyd4WnvhU#t=141

Comment: The question is about a weapon that can knock someone THROUGH a wall, not knocking over a wall, if you wanted to knock a wall why just not use a shell ?